# How do I install dcm2niix?

Tags: apt, software-installation, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install the program `dcm2niix` onto Ubuntu on Windows 10. I have found the `.exe` file but nothing happens when I click on it. I also tried `sudo apt install dcm2niix` on the terminal and it was unable to locate the package. Ubuntu can find `dcm2nii` but not this newer version that is `dcm2niix`.

I also found the program here but I do not know how to open these `.deb` files: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dcm2niix

I am just wondering how I can get this program so I can run it as a command on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

If you find a package on https://packages.ubuntu.com for your release that means you can install it using `apt` and this exact package name, provided you have its repository (`universe` in this case) activated in your software sources. If you don’t or don’t know, you can do so with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

After that install the package with:

```
sudo apt install dcm2niix
```

When installed successfully you have the commands `dcm2niix` as well as `dcm2niibatch` at your disposal, as well as `man` pages for both these commands. An example command line converting images from `/path/to/dicom_dir`, compressing them with `pigz` (`-z` option) and saving them in `/path/to/nifti_dir` (`-o` option) is:

```
dcm2niix -o /path/to/nifti_dir -z y /path/to/dicom_dir
```

#### Further reading

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/507051)
- [`man dcm2niix`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dcm2niix.1.html)
- [`man dcm2niibatch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dcm2niibatch.1.html)